Are bracketing commas around weak interruptions mandatory?
I'm sometimes trying to write in a way that minimizes the amount of punctuation clutter, but I don't want to omit anything considered absolutely mandatory. Would I be required to put bracketing commas around weak interruptions? I can find a ton of rule listings that have these as a thing to do, but none of them specify if this is mandatory.
For example:

I walked over to the elderly man who was wearing a long jacket, and I waved back at him.

(Update: intended to be a situation where there is no other person around, so the information about the jacket isn't needed to clarify which man it is.)
Sorry that it's a slightly clumsy way to word it, I'm just trying to figure out the commas here. So if I'm not entirely confused here, the weak interruption rule would make "who was wearing a long jacket" such an interruption (or am I miscategorizing that here?), and hence if I considered these commas mandatory, I would probably need to write:

I walked over to the elderly man, who was wearing a long jacket, and I waved back at him.

But is it a mandatory comma to use?
Sorry if I somehow worded this question in a confusing manner, feel free to edit it.

The "single comma" version is "unusual", since who was wearing a long jacket is a (potentially discardable) parenthetical element that would normally be set off by commas before and after. But forget the idea that you're looking for a "rule" - just ask yourself whether you would pause in speech. The commas are only there to reflect spoken pauses, so if you read the sentence aloud without a pause before who, it should be obvious to you that's not what you meant to say. With no pause, you're singling out that old man (as opposed to other people you didn't go up to).

This question is similar to: Is it appropriate to put a comma before "which"?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Note that which and who are syntactically equivalent in this context.

...also note that the continuous form I'm sometimes trying to write in a way... is idiomatically "unusual". Native speakers would normally use Simple Present I sometimes try to write in a way... But why only sometimes ?

Since you call it a 'weak interruption', I assume you mean what FumbleFingers calls 'a potentially discardable, parenthetical element' rather than a way of identifying the man you are talking about. If you do, it would be usual to put commas before and after. If it's an identifying clause, I would leave out the comma.

If the comma is not included, you are using a defining/identifier relative clause: [the elderly man who was wearing a long jacket] identifies which elderly man is involved (the one wearing a long jacket). // If the comma is included, you are adding an additional piece of information in a non-defining/descriptor relative clause. This needs offsetting with a pair of commas [ ... the elderly man, who was wearing a long jacket, ...] or alternatively a pair of dashes, or a pair of brackets.

Is there a reason for the comma between "jacket" and "and"? Is it to close the "which" clause or to precede the second main clause "and I waved..."? Either usage would be optional/a stylistic choice (as in the previous discussion).

@Stuart F I'd retain the comma after jacket even with the defining variant, for ease of parsing the longish sentence, and to facilitate breathing if read aloud ... also, to mark where most people would pause in reading aloud. // A more plausible sentence would be preferable ('walked over to ... and waved back at' ?)

You might want to read usage of brackets, parentheses etc; zero punctuation round parentheticals is not totally forbidden, but has to be used only where it does not make unclear.

@EdwinAshworth for clarification, the idea was that nobody else is around, so it wouldn't be an identifying clause.

In such cases (but you need to specify this in the context; [eg 'There were three women, two young men and a rather older one in the room....']:  it was too late an addition to the Qn)  I believe the 'comma required before non-defining relative clause' mantra isn't absolutely binding. But I'd certainly strongly advise against dropping it here; the compounding  ', and I waved back at him.' virtually makes mandatory the comma-required rule of thumb.

Is it required in other cases when the non-defining relative clause is in the middle of another one? This was my original intent, I perhaps picked a bad example. I wondered about cases e.g. like "The man who liked to smoke walked over and reached for the brass box with the tools," where there is no other man around.
